# Is there any DB2 solution which transforms a BLOB (> 32 K) to a CLOB?

Tags: db2, blob, clob

I MUST store XMLs (size > **32K**) in a **BLOB** field in a DB2 database.

In an external source I need a **CLOB**, which p**reserves the XML structure**.

WHEN I run this then I get only the text content:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(
  XMLCAST (
    XMLPARSE (
      DOCUMENT CAST (
        PAYLOAD AS BLOB
      ) 
      PRESERVE WHITESPACE
    ) as XML
  ) as CLOB )
FROM 
U.Content;
```

Is there any DB2 solution which transforms a BLOB (> 32 K) to a CLOB?

Comment: What do you mean with "preserve XML structure"? Is this in the sense of the XML standard or do you mean the original format including whitespaces, typos, ...?

Comment: All database systems have something like CAST, https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-cast-specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XMLSERIALIZE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-xmlserialize) instead of XMLCAST:

```
SELECT
  LENGTH (B) BLOB_LEN
, LENGTH 
  (
    -- BLOB -> XML -> CLOB
    XMLSERIALIZE (XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT B) AS CLOB (100K))
  ) XML_LEN
FROM 
(
  VALUES 
  -- ~100K BLOB from XML doc
  XMLSERIALIZE (XMLELEMENT (NAME "DOC", REPEAT (CLOB ('A'), 100000)) AS BLOB (100K))
) T (B)
```

| BLOB_LEN | XML_LEN |
| --- | --- |
| 100011 | 100011 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wZPsahiJ)